# Struct vs static class for a shared resource?

Tags: c#

I have a product image class. This is an object with re-use potential for general work with images (e.g. for a product, for a CMS when working with images, etc). It will let me set the title of the file, and edit the image in simple ways using standard .NET classes.

I can use a struct, which means if I use the struct in 5 different places, that's 5 different memory locations but all indepdent of each other. Change the state of one these memory locations does not effect the others (which is the desired behaviour). It will be boxed when asking for an object.

The object is instance based. So every product would use the product object and work with the image (e.g. edit its title, etc).

If I make a static class, that is five different locations referring to one object. So I would need to take care of thread synchronization. I can't just write to a variable as another access might overwrite the variable, regardless of how well I synchronize access to this shared resource. So I always need to return new variables. Also, if I use a static class which is used by many different calling methods, that would cause a queue to access the shared resource. Because utility classes are static and they are just that - utilities - they will be used by many classes throughout my codebase. Is it perhaps not wise to use static classes in this situation?

As the MSDN documentation explains, I will only use a static class for a global entity. So a class which encapsulates details about my codebase - there is only one codebase, and this class will contain details on the line count, etc. This is not instance based, like an order class (1 customer-1 order-1 or more orders).

In this sort of scenario, is it a good design decision to perhaps use a struct instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear to me what you want to use this type as, but it sounds like might be best off creating an immutable reference type. It's very rarely appropriate to create your own structs in .NET (and particularly a "product" struct sounds like it's almost certainly the wrong choice) and a static class shouldn't generally have any mutable state except potentially for things like counters.

Is there any reason you haven't gone for a normal class? Make it immutable if you want to be able to share a single instance between multiple "parents" without worrying about any parent changing the contents - add extra methods which return a new instance based on the old one but changed in some way, just like `String.Replace` does.

Comment: Hi. I intend on making a standard image class. The requirement is for an ecommerce engine, but I can see immediate potential for re-use. The only reason I didn't go for a reference type was because I'd be changing all references when 1 ref changes. I guess it should be immutable and ref type.

Comment: Yup, sounds like a great example of where an immutable reference type is appropriate.

Comment: Yup. The object will be used by various sub-systems of the system so immutable is the way to go. Seems like the reason to use a struct is based on scenario not performance. Correct me if I am wrong. To prevent boxing, I could use a struct and create a method asking for a value type param.

Comment: The reason not to use a struct is more philosophical, IMO. This doesn't sound like it's a sort of atomic, naturally unchanging value in the way that a number or a letter is. Writing your own structs in .NET is very rare, IME. It *is* hard to really explain my gut feelings  about it though.

Comment: Fair enough. This link helps me - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664655(VS.71).aspx . Seems like structs would be really useful in desinging a 3d modelling application, where I would be designing a programatic 3d model which uses points, etc. I should remember this in that scenario.

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, the time to worry about performance problems is after you have a performance problem. Until then, worry about making the code work and be maintainable. You will otherwise find yourself chasing insignificant performance gains, or possibly solving the wrong performance problem.